# Disable Outlook Calendar notifications for unresponded events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

It seems that the default for invited events in Outlook is to remind me. Even if I haven't actually accepted the event. If I do accept the event, it still seems to be the default so I would have to disable the reminder manually anyway.

This is silly. I want the items on my calendar, but they aren't important enough that I need a work-interrupting modal reminder about them. Is there any sensible way to disable the reminders?

To provide some context, in my group it is common for users to send the whole group invitations to let us know when people are busy / out of office / shared time-sensitive tasks etc. I need to know about these things, but I don't need a reminder ever 15 minutes to tell me my coworker has gone to a client's site.

Using Outlook 2007 with Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Invitations sent to you by others have individual reminder properties set by the originator. If there isn't a reminder property set, it will use what you have set in your calendar options. There isn't a *"sensible way"* I know of to turn off the reminders other than individually.

Here are some possible solutions;

1. Turn off the default reminder in your Outlook.
2. Ask those sending the invitation to turn off the reminders.
3. Use [shared calendars](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/share-your-calendar-information-HA001230249.aspx) so you can see the events, but they are not on your calendar and therefore not triggering reminders.

There might be a way to do it with VBA, but that is not a simple solution if you are not familiar with how to implement it.